# android mediaplayer() supported file formats

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, file-format

Would like to know the audio formats supported by android mediaplayer class. I tried testing with .mp3, .wav and .ogg file. Which other file formats are supported?

I am using **Xamarin** for developing the app. Would it be any difference for native and xamarin apps?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at supported file formats:
 https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html.

[xamarin](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

> Set the output file audio format using the SetOutputFormat method. For
>   a list of supported audio types see [Android Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: These are the formats supported by Android platform, would it be same for xamarin mediaplayer class?